# vba number format write specific text

Tags: vba, custom-formatting

i am pretty new in using VBA for Excel, but after some searching without result i guess i need some help from you.

I am trying to format a specific cell so that, if one condition is met, it shows the value from another cell, but preceded by a specific text, like "Constantin". So, the displayed result would be, for example Constantin 80.25 .

The code that i'm trying looks like this:

```
    If Cells(4, 1) < 0 Then

    With Range("A1")
    .NumberFormat = "'Constantin' 0.00"
    .Value = - Cells(4, 1)

    End With

    End If
```

I know the syntax is not right, this is my problem, i guess i can't find the right syntax. I hope I'm not bothering you with this, probably, simple question, but i just couldn't find what i needed. Thanks a lot

Comment: replace the 2 lines in your `With` with the following `.Value = "Constantin" & Cells(4, 1).Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't need the word as part of the actual format, in which case something like this will suffice:

```
If Cells(4, 1).Value < 0 Then
    Range("A1").Value = "Constantin " & (Cells(4, 1).Value * -1)
End If
```

If you *really* wanted to use a `With` block then:

```
With Cells(4, 1)
    If .Value < 0 Then
        Range("A1").Value = "Constantin " & (.Value * -1)
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Ok, it seems to work now. One more question though - how can I reduce the number of decimals to one, for example? Now i get a number with 13 decimals. Thanks

Comment: `"Constantin " & WorksheetFunction.Round(.Value * -1, 1)` should do the trick ;)

Comment: i wrote my code in a module and this might be the reason i get this error "invalid or unqualified reference", with the ".value" selected, when i try to compile the code with the line you sugested

Comment: The whole line would be `Range("A1").Value = "Constantin " & WorksheetFunction.Round((.Value * -1), 1)` <-- is that what you've got?

Comment: 'If Cells(4, 1).Value < 0 Then
    
    Range("A1").Value = "Constantin " & WorksheetFunction.Round((.Value * -1), 1)
    
End If' this is what i wrote and got the same error

Comment: ok, seems like the problem was that it needed to be WorksheetFunction.Round((cells(4.1.Value * -1), 1) not just WorksheetFunction.Round((.Value * -1), 1)

Comment: Are you using the `With` block? Or the first version?

Comment: Hm, ok, i was using the simple version (the first one); i guess those lines would have worked inside the `with` block; so, it was just a misunderstanding; but it works in the end, thanks

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark as the answer if it helped :)